# How do I solve this missing attribute error in this subclass IceCreamStand in the superclass Restaurant in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I am in the middle of learning how to create subclasses to a superclass in python. I have created an IceCreamStand subclass to the superclass Restaurant and then gave the subclass a specific attribute. The only problem is when I go to print out the attribute of the subclass, it says that the subclass does not have this attribute.

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, name, cuisine_type):
            """Initialize attributes to describe restaurant."""
            self.name = name
            self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
            self.number_served = 23
        

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"The restaurant name is {self.name}.")
        print(f"This restaurant is a {self.cuisine_type} restaurant.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
         print(f"{self.name} is now open.")

    def set_number_served(self, new_number_served):
        self.number_served = new_number_served

    def increment_number_served(self, increment):
        self.number_served += increment

class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
    def __init__(self, name, cuisine_type):
        super().__init__(name, cuisine_type)
        self.flavor = "Vanilla"

    def display_flavors(self):
        print("The flavor they offer:")
        print(self.flavor)
        

creamStand = IceCreamStand("Jace's Ice Cream", "Ice cream")

creamStand.describe_restaurant()
creamStand.display_flavors()
```

[Output Error of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjbI1.png)

I was expecting to get the specific subclass attribute after the other superclass attributes were displayed and never got it.

Comment: Please include the error output in the post as text

Comment: Your code works for me in Python 3.8.8 what is your version? (base) $ python icec.py 
The restaurant name is Jace's Ice Cream.
This restaurant is a Ice cream restaurant.
The flavor they offer:
Vanilla
$ python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 19:58:26) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: You code works as expected without any error.

Comment: Actually @Mike fixed it for you. You had a typo in your code. See the edit history (`__intit__`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `__init__()`... your original (which I edited) had a typo which used `__intit__()`

```py
class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
    def __init__(self, name, cuisine_type):
        super().__init__(name, cuisine_type)
        self.flavor = "Vanilla"

    def display_flavors(self):
        print("The flavor they offer:")
        print(self.flavor)
```